# Unable to import Dll written in C++ into C# .NetCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, dll, dllexport, interopservices

I wrote a simple dll using C++. When I import it in a c# .NetStandard project, it works correctly. But when I import it in c# .NetCore project it throws an exception  `System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

Dll import code for both .NetCore and .NetStandard are same

```
const string dllLocation = "StringLibrary";
[DllImport(dllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void splitstring();
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Are you sure all is in the same bit version and you are not mixing x86 and x64?

Comment: @StefanoCavion The C++ library is in 86 and C# is in AnyCpu

Comment: is the flag  Prefer 32 Bit enabled?